# Could Old English /ea/ be a derivative from /a/?

Tags: vowels, sound-change, old-english

"...This includes changes from **the split between Old English and Old Frisian** (c. AD 475)..." [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English#Old_English_period)

The reflex of Proto-Germanic *au is spelled *ea* in Old English, but spelled *a* in Old Frisian. For example:

- Proto-Germanic: augô Old English (West Saxon) ēage Old Frisian: āge
- Proto-Germanic: auʀā Old English (West Saxon): ēare Old Frisian: āre

How did these develop from Proto-Germanic *au? Is the reflex of *au reconstructed as remaining /au/ up until the split between Old English and Frisian? Or had *au changed to *a* already in Proto-Anglo-Frisian, followed by a change of *a* to *ea* in Old English, but not in Frisian?

Comment: Do you mean "Anglo-Frisian", or "Ingvaeonic", or "West Germanic"? There are a lot of stages that have been reconstructed between Proto-Germanic and Old English and I'm not sure what exactly you're talking about here.

Comment: I'm also not sure what PGmc \*au has to do with anything; the famous sound change *ā > *ǣ > ea in certain environments ("near") is separate from the sound change *au > ea ("death").

Comment: @Draconis PGmc **au**gô OE (West Saxonic) **ea**ge OFS **a**ge PGmc **au**ʀā OE **ea**re OFS **a**re

Comment: @Draconis I do not understand this *au > ea. I understand PGmc au > Proto-Anglo-Frisian a > OE ea

Comment: @Draconis I did not find the reconstraction of PGmc au for Proto-Anglo-Frisian

Comment: I still can't tell what you're asking. There's a famous sound change that turned *ā into ea in some environments (Anglo-Frisian brightening and Old English breaking), and a separate sound change that turned *au into ea. As far as I know they're not connected.

Comment: @brasstacks Ahh, thank you! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be settled whether Proto-Germanic *au was monophthongized before developing to Old English *ea. A development to a monophthong (as you suggest) has been proposed by Raymond Page ("The Old English Rune *Ear,* *Medium Ævum* Vol 30, No 2. (1961), 65–79, my access through JSTOR), who I found discussed in "[Palatalization of Velars:A Major Link of Old English and Old Frisian](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c929/fbdb1d322b568421024734fb63a8fbb0215c.pdf)", by Stephen Laker. Laker points out that this could not have been the same monophthong as the one that developed from Proto-Germanic *ai.

Laker however also mentions three alternative proposals in the section "4.3 Palatalization in Old English before +ea, (< Gmc *au)", (pages 177-180).

- per Karl Luick and Kurt Goblirsch : Proto-Germanic *au > Anglo-Frisian *æa, monophthongization Anglo-Frisian *æa > *ā in Pre-Old Frisian.
- per  Robert Fulk : Proto-Germanic *au > Anglo-Frisian *æu, Pre-Old Frisian reversal of this change  *æu > *au followed by *au > *ā
- *au > æa as a relatively late sound change in Old English after the split from Frisian

A side note that has some relevance. As far as I know, there is not even total consensus on the exact phonetic form of Old English *ēa* itself. It seems generally agreed that it started with the same quality as *æ* and *ǣ,* generally taken to be more or less IPA [æ]. The quality of the second element and the quantitative structure of the diphthong are however disputed. Many authors indicate the second element is [ɑ], like *a*; others instead describe it as [ə] (Donka Minkova, *[A Historical Phonology of English](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Historical_Phonology_of_English/uGs3BQAAQBAJ?q=&gbpv=1#f=false)*, 2014, §6.5.3 Diphthongs and Diphthongoids).

The *ēa* from the original diphthong *au merged in Old English with *ēa* from the breaking of long *ǣ*, but is known to be distinct from the homographic *ea* that developed from breaking of short *æ.* Some authors treat these as diphthongs that are respectively long and short (hence, they are commonly distinguished by writing the first as *ēa* and the second as *ea*). Other authors argue that the short sound should not be categorized as a genuine diphthong; it is possible to treat the short sound as some kind of allophone of /a/ (Old English short *a, ea,* and *æ* are mostly in complementary distribution), an analysis that makes it unambiguous to transcribe *ēa* without a length mark as [æɑ] or [æə].

We can broadly say that the Old English form seems to show fronting and raising of the initial element, and lowering and unrounding of the second element, but the ordering of these processes and exactly how they occurred seems difficult to determine.

Comment: By the way, In my opinion Old Frisian /ā/ is a derivative from /ia/ (by umlaut of the first element of the diphtong ia) like PIE /ou/ from /eu/, PGmc /au/ from /eu/ or Gothic /au/ from /iu/. The difference is (as I see it) that Old Frisian turned the second element /u/ to /a/ thus Old Frisian /ā/ is simply /aa/ derived from /ia/ by umlaut.

Comment: or like Old High German /ō/ is a derivative from /io/ (by umlaut of the first element of the diphtong io) The difference is that OHG turned the second element /u/ to /o/ thus OHG /ō/ is simply /oo/ derived from /io/ by umlaut (as I see it)

Comment: Excellent explanation! The one thing I'd add is that, to my understanding, breaking happened only in certain environments (notably before h), while the development *au > ea was universal, so the merger between those two couldn't have happened before OE.